# Long TRUNCATE operations

Tags: sql-server-2019, tempdb, truncate

On Microsoft SQL Server 2019, there is a lot of long temp tables TRUNCATE operations with time over 5..10 seconds.
Easy query like "TRUNCATE TABLE #tt22" can take over 15 seconds.
It's an intermittent problem, sometimes it disappears for a day after restarting the server .
What could be the reason?

UPD:
According to the latest performance measurements, long TRUNCATE operations are observed not only in temporary tables, but also in physical ones.

Comment: If you run [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) in a separate query window, while the truncation is hanging, what are the results? Specifically any blocking and what are the wait types on the truncation query?

Comment: It's difficult to catch the situation when truncate hangs. I only see this in extended events.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much that can be said without the aforementioned information. Only other idea is maybe you're misinterpreting the Extended Events. It's not usual for truncation to take a long time.

Comment: @J.D. There is no any blocking. Wait type is SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD

Comment: Was there any other processes / queries running at the same time? You should save the entire results you see from `sp_WhoIsActive` in case there are other clues. Also, next time you notice the problem, you should run `sp_WhoIsActive` multiple times in a row (10+) to see if you catch any other wait types for the `TRUNCATE` query, or if every time it's the same wait type of `SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD`. (Some queries have multiple things they're waiting on.)

Comment: @J.D. Yes, other processes/requests were running at the same time. Long TRUNCATE queries have a wait type of SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD, those that are fast MISCELLANEOUS.

Comment: Can you add the results of `sp_WhoIsActive` to your Post? What kind of disks does your `tempdb` live on? Are there any other things that use those same disks or anything else that runs on that server, like antivirus?

Comment: @J.D. We use our own proprietary monitoring system, so there is no need for sp_WhoIsActive as such.
The disk (IBM5200 nvme FCM HBA 32gbps) is allocated only for the needs of tempdb.   
There is no antivirus or any other programs installed on server.  It is important to note that after restarting, these delays disappear for about a day. Then they appear again. And the duration of TRUNCATE increases gradually every day and so on until the next restart.

Comment: Strange. Only other things I can suggest is looking in both the SQL Server Logs and Windows Event Logs around the time a slow `TRUNCATE` occurs. Also, when it becomes slow again, try running [CrystalDiskMark](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-fast-your-san-or-how-slow/) to see if the issue is coming from the disk itself (and as a way to eliminate it being a SQL Server issue).

Comment: The problem does not appear all the time, only some requests are executed for a long time, even within the same session.
There is no drawdown in disk storage performance.
There are no errors in the logs either. What other variants are there?

Comment: Please run CrystalDiskMark against the disk the next time you have an issue, and report back the results. I'm out of ideas otherwise. Only other thing I could take a shot in the dark on is if it's some kind of weird VLF issue if you have a huge number of VLFs, but I don't know much about VLFs.

Comment: We did research based on Monica Rathbun's article https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/vlfs-the-forgotten-foe/ but the number of virtual log files didn't increase after restarting SQL server. However, long running TRUNCATE queries on temporary tables remained.
P.S. Run CrystalDiskMark unfortunately is not possible.

Comment: "*Run CrystalDiskMark unfortunately is not possible*" - Why's that?

Comment: @J.D. As I said earlier, we use our own proprietary monitoring system and do not have direct access to the server. However, we observe a problem not only in monitoring, but also in user reviews.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll need someone who does have access to the file share of the drive for which tempdb is on (doesn't need to be direct access to the server itself - can be just the UNC path) to test things like CrystalDiskMark, if you want to be able to debug your problem further.

Comment: What kind of metrics we need from CrystalDiskMark?

Comment: Please see my original link to the Brent Ozar article on using it. But essentially you should focus on the results for `SEQ1M Q8T1` and `RND4K Q32T16` and see if they make sense relative to the type of disk you have behind the `tempdb` drive. E.g. if you're using an NVMe, which typically gets speeds of over 1,000 MB/s, and your results show you're only getting 100 MB/s then you know something's wrong with the disk, and can rule out SQL Server. Even the common SSD these days should get at least 400 MB/s on average.

Comment: UPD: According to the latest performance measurements, long TRUNCATE operations are observed not only in temporary tables, but also in physical ones. Since the tables are located on different disks, we can completely eliminate disks performance issues.

Comment: "*Since the tables are located on different disks, we can completely eliminate disks performance issues.*" - Well that's not necessarily true. Is your server a VM?...if so, the disks may still be the same physical disk, even though they are logically different drive letters / mappings. I'd recommend running CrystalDiskMark against both logical drives. Someone else on here recently had a very similar issue and almost ruled out the disk being the issue because multiple logical drives were affected, and didn't realize they shared the same physical disk.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a MS bug.
This situation could be reproduced in a test environment:
MSSQL 2019 after some hours of work increases truncate time from milliseconds till nn seconds. In that case there were #tmp tables in 1c system.  After sqlserver service reboot truncates became speedy again but for only some hours.

Russian leading performance team "Softpoint" investigations and attempts to work around that problem:

https://habr.com/ru/companies/softpoint/articles/739112/

Comment: Its not really an answer

Comment: @RohitGupta This can serve as a hint to solve the problem.